# What's the healtpoint of various enemies in uprising and coop overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

Anyone knows and make a list? Anyone make estimate?

For example, that heavy assault can withstand like a few rip tire. Looks like his HP is like 3k or something.

Any lists?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, it isn't possible to add these enemies to a game via the Workshop, but according to the Overwatch Fandom Wiki, we have the following data (some of these will vary by difficulty but the data is incomplete).

### Talon Forces

- [Trooper](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/Talon_Trooper): 200
- [Enforcer](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/Talon_Enforcer): 900 (450 HP + 450 shields)
- [Sniper](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/Talon_Sniper): 700 (350 HP + 350 shields)
- [Assassin](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/Talon_Assassin): 1200 (750 HP + 450 shields)
- [Heavy Assault](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/Talon_Heavy_Assault): 1800

### Null Sector

- [Nulltrooper](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/Nulltrooper): 200 (100 HP + 100 armor)
- [Eradicator](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/Eradicator): 400 (200 HP + 200 armor)
- [Slicer](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/Slicer): *no data available yet, but I'd guess 200*
- [Detonator](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/Detonator): 1000
- [Bastions](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/B73-NS): 1500 (1000 HP + 500 armor)
- [OR-14](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/OR14-NS): 1500 (1000 HP + 500 armor)

Comment: on what difficulty is this?

Comment: The stats for the Enforcer are specifically for Legendary, but the others are uncertain for now.